# In Scala, why does my Sieve algorithm runs so slowly?

Tags: performance, scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes using lists and filters rather than arrays and looping. I'm not sure why the following performs significantly worse than an imperative equivalent. 1 million should absolutely fly but my machine grinds to a halt.

```
  val max = 1000000
  def filterPrimes(upper: Int, seed: Int = 2, sieve: List[Int] = List()): List[Int] =
    sieve.map(x => if (x % seed == 0 && x > seed) 0 else x).filter(_ > 0)

  var filtered: List[Int] = (2 to max).toList
  for (i <- 2 to max / 2) filtered = filterPrimes(max, i, filtered)
  filtered.foreach(println(_))
```

Comment: I'd replace `sieve.map(x => if (x % seed == 0 && x > seed) 0 else x).filter(_ > 0)` with `sieve.filter(x => x % seed != 0 || x == seed)`.

Comment: Even Dan Burton and user unknown haven't pointed out that your code here is not a Sieve of Eratosthenes (SoE), but rather a Trial Division Prime Sieve (TDPS) as it doesn't follow the Eratosthenes algorithm of only using additions to cull prime composites as in their quite imperative fastest solutions (they use mutability of index var's in the inner culling loops; one could rewrite their code to use functional forms of loop not requiring mutability except for the array or Bitset contents at little or no cost in speed). This is TDPS because checks for factors of each trial number by division.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few potential issues, although I don't really see a single "smoking gun"...  Anyway, here's what I've got.  First:

```
sieve.map(x => if (x % seed == 0 && x > seed) 0 else x).filter(_ > 0)
```

could be written more concisely as:

```
sieve.filter(x => x <= seed || x % seed != 0)
```

Next, `upper` is unused in `filterPrimes` (this should have no effect on performance though).

Third, don't use a `var` and a `for` loop if you want to really use a pure functional style, instead turn `filterPrimes` into a tail-recursive function.  The compiler might be clever enough to optimize away the copies if you do it this way (although I wouldn't hold my breath).

Finally, and probably most importantly, your `for` loop is wasting a huge amount of time filtering out values that have necessarily already been filtered.  For example, it tries to filter multiples of 4 after already having filtered all multiples of 2.  If you want to use this sieve algorithm efficiently, you need to choose your seeds from the remaining elements in the list.

In other words, keep an *index* into the list, and determine the seed from the index, like:

```
iteration 0: 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
      index: ^

iteration 1: 2 3 5 7 9 ...
      index:   ^

iteration 2: 2 3 5 7 ...
      index:     ^
```

this avoids the duplicate effort.  Also, you don't need to keep iterating until you get to `max`, I think you can actually stop when you get past `sqrt(max)`.

Comment: I think it's safe to say that `for (i <- 2 to max / 2)` is the "single smoking gun", for two reasons you described: "it tries to filter multiples of 4 after already having filtered all multiples of 2 [etc]" and "I think you can actually stop when you get past sqrt(max)"

Comment: Sure, but I'm assuming @deltanovember is doing the same thing in his imperative version that he's comparing performance against.  I dunno, maybe that's a bad assumption :)

Answer (score 10):

If you'd like to see a functional way of doing the sieve, check out [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf).

Comment: +1 That is a great read and debunks the "golf sieve" so often tossed about.

Answer (score 5):

I would make a few modifications.

- It seems odd that you perform `filterPrimes` for *all numbers* between `2` and `max / 2`, the "actual" sieve technique requires you only perform `filterPrimes` for *all primes* between `2` and `sqrt(max)`.
- It also seems odd that you use a var and a for loop. To do it the "functional" way, I would use a recursive function instead.
- Instead of performing `filterPrimes` on the entire list, you can collect the primes as you go; no need to throw those through the filter over and over.
- It is rather strange to `map` and then `filter` the way you do, since the map simply flags which elements to filter, you can accomplish the same using only filter.

So here was my first attempt at these modifications:

```
def filterFactors(seed: Int, xs: List[Int]) = {
  xs.filter(x => x % seed != 0)
}

def sieve(max: Int) = {
  def go(xs: List[Int]) : List[Int] = xs match {
    case y :: ys => {
      if (y*y > max) y :: ys
      else y :: go(filterFactors(y, ys))
    }
    case Nil => Nil
  }

  go((2 to max).toList)
}
```

However, this reflects my Haskell bias, and has a huge flaw: it will take up a huge amount of stack space, due to the recursive call `y :: go(...)` in the `go` helper function. Running `sieve(1000000)` resulted in an "OutOfMemoryError" for me.

Let's try a common FP trick: tail recursion with accumulators.

```
def sieve(max: Int) = {
  def go(xs: List[Int],
         acc: List[Int])
         : List[Int] = xs match {
    case y :: ys => {
      if (y*y > max) acc.reverse ::: (y :: ys)
      else go(filterFactors(y, ys), y :: acc)
    }
    case Nil => Nil
  }

  go((2 to max).toList, Nil)
}
```

By adding an accumulator value we are able to write the `go` helper function in tail-recursive form, thus avoiding the huge stack problem from before. (Haskell's evaluation strategy is very different; it therefore neither needs nor benefits from tail recursion)

Now let's compare speed with an imperative, mutation-based approach.

```
def mutationSieve (max: Int) = {
    var arr: Array[Option[Int]] =
        (2 to max).map (x => Some (x)).toArray
    var i = 0
    var seed = (arr (i)).get
    while (seed * seed < max) {
        for (j: Int <- (i + seed) to (max - 2) by seed) {
          arr (j) = None
        }
        i += 1
        while (arr (i).isEmpty) {
          i += 1
        }
        seed = (arr (i)).get
    }
    arr.flatten
}
```

Here I use an `Array[Option[Int]]`, and "cross off" a number by replacing its entry with "None". There is a tiny bit of room for optimization; perhaps a small speed boost could be obtained by using an array of bools, where the index represents the particular number. Whatever.

Using very primitive techinques (carefully placed `new Date()` calls...) I benchmarked the functional version to be approximately 6 times slower than the imperative version. It is clear that the two approaches have the same big-Oh time complexity, but the constant factors involved in programming with linked lists do incur a cost.

I also benchmarked your version, using `Math.sqrt(max).ceil.toInt` instead of `max / 2`: it was about 15x slower than the functional version I presented here. Interestingly, it is estimated[<sup>1</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) that approximately 1 out of every 7 numbers between 1 and 1000 (`sqrt(1000000)`) is prime (1 / ln(1000)), therefore, **a large part of the slowdown can be attributed to the fact that you perform the loop on every single number, while I perform my function only for every prime.** Of course, if it took 15x as long to perform ~1000 iterations, **it would take ~7500x as long to perform 500000 iterations**, which is why your original code is agonizingly slow.

Comment: +1 Benchmarking for the OP and a nice analysis.  Now _that's_ a helpful answer.

Comment: I bet you can make your imperative version *much* faster by using either a primitive array or a BitSet.

Comment: I guess `go (2 :: (3 to max by 2).toList, Nil)` would improve the speed a little for 2 of the solutions.

Comment: @userunknown Added `fromSome` right before `mutationSieve`. Also, using the "wheel" technique (described in the academic paper Ken linked to) would improve the speed even more. If I were more of a Scala buff, I would've tried using streams and wheels.

Comment: @ziggystar using a BitSet, I was able to get about a 3x speedup. [bitset version on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/d4Lvf), [option array version on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/A656R). I can't imagine any imperative version of this same technique being faster than a BitSet, assuming scala's mutable BitSets are implemented well.

Comment: @Dan Burton Well factor three is not that bad, isn't it?

Comment: @ziggystar a 3x speedup is definitely a Good Thing; that places the list-based code at ~18x slower than the BitSet code. I was pleasantly surprised at both the speedup and the clarity of the BitSet code; I was expecting it to be a lot nastier. Thanks for the tip to use BitSet :) I hadn't heard of it before.

Comment: @DanBurton: I allowed myself to modify your code a bit, after I understood `fromSome` :) a) Instead of fromSome, you call `get` for an Option which is a Some for sure. And b) arr.map (! _.isEmpty).fromSome became just `arr.flatten`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fast sieve, implementing hints of mergeconflict and some of the hints from the paper, mentioned by Ken Wayne VanderL :

```
def createPrimes (MAX: Int) : Array[Boolean] = {
  val pri = (false :: false :: true :: List.range (3, MAX + 1).map (_ % 2 != 0)).toArray
  for (i <- List.range (3, MAX)
    if (pri (i))) {
      var j = 2 * i;
      while (j < MAX) {
        if (pri (j))
          pri (j) = false;
        j += i;
      }
    }
  pri
}
val MAX = 1000*1000
(1 to MAX).filter (createPrimes (MAX))
```

Comparing graph:
[image: graph comparing 4 algos with different MAX-sizes]
The vertical axis shows seconds, the horizontal is from 100 000 to 1 000 000 primes.
The deltaNovember-algorithm is already improved to run to math.sqrt(max) only, and the filtering, suggested by Alexey Romanov in the comment. From Dan Burton I took the second algorithm and the last one with a small modification, to fit my Interface (List, not Array) and the bitSet Sieve, which he only linked to in a comment, but which is the fastest.

Comment: Fancy graph :) very cool. Important to notice how `deltaNovember` grows more rapidly than the others, because, if I'm not mistaken its main loop is performed *O(n)* times where the "main loop" of the others is performed *O(n/log(n))* times. `log(n)` is a small difference, but a difference nonetheless. `fromSome` was just a little hack to extract the `a` out of an `Option[a]`, intended for use only when you are already sure that it is `Some(x)` and not `None`. I added the code to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks, I made the graph with gnuplot, and my own microbenchmark framework, available here: https://gist.github.com/1152783, which creates the input for gnuplot. For bigger samples (5M) I repeated the test without deltaNovembers approach, and got a similar result - your mutationSieve leading. I didn't read the paper with the wheel - maybe I should, but it seems hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are immutable and every call to `filterPrimes` creates a new list.  You are creating a lot of lists, which is, by the way, unnecessary.

Go with your first instinct (what you probably call the "imperative equivalent") which I am guessing uses a **single** mutable array.

(Edited to make clear that I understood that the creation of multiple lists was unnecessary.)